# Не срабатывает контексменю

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть табличка. И  мне нужно  чтобы когда я  жму правую кнопку  за табличкой  срабатывал контекс меню. Но не работает:

```
void TeacherWidget::contexMenuCategory(const QPoint pos)
{
   QMenu* menu = new QMenu(this);

   QAction* createAction = new QAction("Создать", this);
   QAction* sortByAction = new QAction("Отсортировать", this);

   connect(createAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(createClicked()));
   connect(sortByAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(sortedClicked()));

   menu->addAction(createAction);
   menu->addAction(sortByAction);
}
```

и  еще такой вопрос. у меня  после создать  должен быть переход на другое меню где я выбираю  с 3  значений что создать. Но я не нашел как  это реализовать. можно пример?

UPD: 
в конструкторе:

```
 this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
mTableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
 connect(mTableView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(contexMenuClicked(const QPoint)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(contexMenuComponent(const QPoint)));
```

И теперь мои функции:

```
 void TeacherWidget::contexMenuClicked(const QPoint pos)
{
   QMenu menu;

   QAction* openAction = new QAction("Открыть", &menu);
   QAction* removeAction = new QAction("Удалить", &menu);

   connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openClicked()));
   connect(removeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(removeClicked()));

   menu.addAction(openAction);
   menu.addAction(removeAction);

   menu.exec(mTableView->mapToGlobal(pos));
}

void TeacherWidget::contexMenuComponent(const QPoint pos)
{

  QMenu menu;

  QAction* createAction = new QAction("Создать", &menu);
  QAction* sortByAction = new QAction("Отсортировать", &menu);

  connect(createAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(createClicked()));
  connect(sortByAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(sortedClicked()));

  menu.addAction(createAction);
  menu.addAction(sortByAction);
  menu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

Comment: `"...Но я не нашел как это реализовать..."` -> `menu->addMenu`. Ну, метод вы показали, а как он связан с таблицей? Например, можно у виджета указать `setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);`, а после соединить сигнал с вашим слотом: `connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(contexMenuCategory(QPoint)));`

Comment: @gil9red я уже сделал под меню. Но с двома контекс меню не работает. Только по одному(ели один за коментить)работает. и я  не  знаю почему..

Answer (score 3):

1.Для `TeacherWidget` должно быть установлено свойство `contextMenuPolicy` в `Qt::CustomContextMenu`

2.Соеденить слот вызова контекстного меню в Вашим слотом, например так:

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::customContextMenuRequested, this, &MainWindow::contexMenuCategory);
```

3.В Вашем коде будут утечки и нет вызова exec(), вот пример без утечек

```
QMenu menu;

QAction* createAction = new QAction("Создать", &menu);
QAction* sortByAction = new QAction("Отсортировать", &menu);

connect(createAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(createClicked()));
connect(sortByAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(sortedClicked()));

menu.addAction(createAction);
menu.addAction(sortByAction);
menu.exec(mapToGlobal(_pos));
```

Исправлено:

Если нужно для разных виджетов разное контекстное меню, это тоже можно сделать:

`mainwindow.h`

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void contexMenuMainWindow(const QPoint &_pos);
    void contexMenuTable(const QPoint &_pos);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    ui->tableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

    connect(this, &QWidget::customContextMenuRequested, this, &MainWindow::contexMenuMainWindow);
    connect(ui->tableView, &QWidget::customContextMenuRequested, this, &MainWindow::contexMenuTable);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::contexMenuMainWindow(const QPoint &_pos)
{
    QMenu menu;

    QAction* createAction = new QAction("Создать для MainWindow", &menu);

    menu.addAction(createAction);
    menu.exec(mapToGlobal(_pos));
}

void MainWindow::contexMenuTable(const QPoint &_pos)
{
    QMenu menu;

    QAction* createAction = new QAction("Создать для Table", &menu);

    menu.addAction(createAction);
    menu.exec(ui->tableView->mapToGlobal(_pos));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Aлександр, проблема в  том что у меня есть  два контекс меню. Одно  только  должно работать в  таблице а  другое  за таблицей    mTableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(mTableView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(contexMenuClicked(const QPoint)));
    connect(mTableView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(contexMenuComponent(const QPoint)));

Comment: Что значит "за таблицей"? за её пределами? Добавите скриншот Вашей формы и отметьте зоны где должны работать разное контекстное меню.

Comment: https://a.radikal.ru/a27/1807/95/0a2a014301ab.png

Comment: красное  это contexMenuClicked

Comment: синие - contexMenuCategory

Comment: @Александр, а где могут быть утечки в коде ТС, если в каждый конструктор передается указатель на родителя?

Comment: Я неверно выразился, утечек не будет, по той причине что указан родитель. Но проблема в том, что все эти экземпляры QMenu будут уничтожены только после удаления родителя, что скорее всего будет при закрытие программы. Соответственно при каждом нажатие будет выделяться память, что в теории может привести к тому, что память для программы просто закончится.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ

Comment: @Александр не срабатывет https://a.radikal.ru/a12/1807/79/6e2017889011.png жму  за  табличкой и  другое мени появляется а не то что нужно

Comment: @Александр в UPD скинул как я  делал

Comment: @Александр наешл в чем  дело: this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    mTableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);  у меня  только  одно с них работает.  оба  одночасно нет

Comment: @Александр я  так и не  нашел почему у меня не работает(((

Comment: @Александр брал ваш код и к себе прикручивал. тоже  только по одельности работате. так как и мой код(((